# Position of placeholder and text is not coming vertically middle in a input text box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have given custom height of a input text box and according to which I want to adjust its placeholder and text vertical middle. I have given css property to its placeholder too. Am i missing anything in it? Thank you in advance.

```css
.input-lg {
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    line-height: 1.9 !important;
}
.form-control {
    border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
    border-radius: 1px;
    height: 24px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #656466;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 0 7px;
      display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color: #c9c9c9;
 font-size: 11px !important;
}
.form-control:-moz-placeholder {
 color: #c9c9c9;
 font-size: 11px !important;
}
.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
 color: #c9c9c9;
 font-size: 11px !important;
}
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
 color: #c9c9c9;
 font-size: 11px !important;
}
 .input-lg::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    vertical-align: middle !important;
     line-height: normal !important;
    opacity:1;
}
.input-lg:-moz-placeholder {
    vertical-align: middle !important;
     line-height: normal !important;
    opacity:1;
 
}
.input-lg::-moz-placeholder {
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    line-height: normal !important;
    opacity:1;
 
}
.input-lg:-ms-input-placeholder {
    vertical-align: middle !important;
     line-height: normal !important;
    opacity:1;
 
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Hint Text">
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
   .input-lg{
     line-height:30px;
   }
```

Fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/np4cctmm/

Comment: Still it's not at middle

Comment: Have you tried it after removing line-height:1.9 and line-height:normal?

Answer (score 0):

I simply added `padding: 0 7px 2px;` to the input

```css
.input-lg {
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    line-height: 1.9 !important;
}
.form-control {
    border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
    border-radius: 1px;
    height: 24px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #656466;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 0 7px 2px;
      display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color: #c9c9c9;
 font-size: 11px !important;
}
.form-control:-moz-placeholder {
 color: #c9c9c9;
 font-size: 11px !important;
}
.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
 color: #c9c9c9;
 font-size: 11px !important;
}
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
 color: #c9c9c9;
 font-size: 11px !important;
}
 .input-lg::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    vertical-align: middle !important;
     line-height: normal !important;
    opacity:1;
}
.input-lg:-moz-placeholder {
    vertical-align: middle !important;
     line-height: normal !important;
    opacity:1;
 
}
.input-lg::-moz-placeholder {
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    line-height: normal !important;
    opacity:1;
 
}
.input-lg:-ms-input-placeholder {
    vertical-align: middle !important;
     line-height: normal !important;
    opacity:1;
 
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Hint Text">
```